# Получить нужные значения из строки

Tags: php

Есть строка с текстом. Среди этого текста есть такой текст

```
<br />Н1 <br>Цена:<br> 170,00 р</a></div>
```

Как получить от сюда **Н1** и **170,00** ?

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Исходя из текущей постановки задачи - взять из строки соответствующие позиции. На основе чего решено, что нужно Н1 и 170,00?

Comment: @Эникейщик да. эти значения нужны в разные переменные записать. эти значения всегда разные

Comment: Что именно "да"?

Comment: @Эникейщик нужно Н1 и 170

Comment: Вы на какой вопрос отвечаете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match('~>(.+?)\s<br>Цена:<br>\s(.+?)\sр</a>~', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

В результате:

```
Array
(
    [0] => >Н1 <br>Цена:<br> 170,00 р</a>
    [1] => Н1
    [2] => 170,00
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '<br />Н1 <br>Цена:<br> 170,00 р</a></div>';
$arr = [];
preg_match('/([^.]\d+).+?(\d+[,.]\d+)/u',$str,$arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

Вывод:

```
Array {
  [0]=> "Н1 <br>Цена:<br> 170,00"
  [1]=> "Н1"
  [2]=> "170,00"
}
```